# Turn off Intellij signature popup

Tags: intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 12, how do I make the popup stop...popping up when I hold Ctrl while hovering over a field/method with the mouse? (see picture)

[image: rage-inducer]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible

Comment: Made an Intellij feature request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115136

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the "Brief Info" action (or at least that is what it is called in the [Keymap reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf).) To the best of my knowledge (i.e. 10+ years of daily IDEA use including all beta/EAP builds), there is no way to turn it off. Searching the settings for either "Brief Info" or "Info" does not show any pertinent setting. Likewise, searching key mappings for the same does not reveal a mapping. In fact in the keymap settings, you can only map mouse clicks, not mouse pointing (i.e. hovering). You can [submit a feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) asking for a setting to disable this feature.

Just put of curiosity, why do you want to disable it? I guess I would never see a case where one would <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MousePoint</kbd> unless they wanted to see this. The only case I can think of would be if you disliked it popping up when you go to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on a symbol. If it is the latter, note that you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in place of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>MousePoint</kbd>

Comment: I am coming from visual studio, where a typical command sequence for me is: Ctrl+Click to select word, and then Ctrl+C or Ctrl+V depending on the situation. Having the bubble spam itself all over frequently puts it in the way of my click. I realize double-click selects word, but it is slower for me and more carpal-tunnel-ly. Additionally, I don't want to Alt+Click for select word because it's slower to input Alt+Click to Ctrl+C/V, and there is no way I'm remapping copy and paste to Alt. I appreciate the definitive answer, though.

Comment: Ah, I had not thought about that use case. Not sure if it will help you, but Ctrl+W will select the current word or item. Repeated hits will select an expanding scope/code-block. Ctrl+Shift+W will deselect.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the "autopop" options under /Settings/IDE Settings/Editor/Code Completion.

Comment: Doing that does not work. Those settings refer to when you're typing, I believe.